# Which DVCS work best with Subversion repositories

Tags: svn, git, mercurial, dvcs, bazaar

Subversion works great when we have access to central repository, but sometimes two or more developers work at client where they do not have connection to central repository. I am looking for DVCS that can help us where off-line.

It should:

- cooperate with Subversion repository so developers can checkout before leave, commit locally where off line and commit to central repository when they return
- easy exchange code between developers working offline
- work on Windows, GUI preferred; developers are used to TortoiseSVN

Anybody uses Bazaar, Mercurial, git or maybe something else and can show its advantages and pitfalls?
So far I started (really returned to) testing Bazaar with Tortoise Bazaar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have tried Git, Mercurial and Bazaar with a SVN repository and I have found that all three work pretty well (when using the their respective *-svn module).

I suggest you pick the DCVS you like most and use that one.

(The modules are [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn), [bzr-svn](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-guide/svn_plugin.html) and [hgSubversion](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgSubversion))

Comment: Thanks. I tested all 3 systems with its Tortoise GUI. To me Bazaar is the best Windows and SVN integrated of those tools (as for now: October 2010). It even has `$Id` kaywors support :)

Answer (score 4):

[HgSubversion](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgSubversion) provides the sort of interaction you're talking about. It bills itself as a SVN client, based in Mercurial, meaning that you work in Mercurial locally, but still interact with a SVN server.

The [convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) is also very good if you want to convert from SVN to Mercurial.

There are some other Mercurial/SVN workflows you might find interesting on the [Mercurial wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion).

Answer (score 2):

Git, works side by side in the same directory, also has git-svn bridges